# Anyone have a favorite iOS icon generator that supports stickers?

Tags: ios, icons, generator

I'm building a stickers app with my kid, and the icons required are different from what my icon generator supports. Anyone found one that will automagically create the right size icons for sticker apps for iOS 10?

Thanks!